# How to blur a specific position in the picture using CustomPainter in flutter

Tags: flutter, blur

Is it possible to add blur effect to picture using painting? If so, how can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Provide more details like what you have tried so far or what's blocking you.

Comment: add more description and details. what exactly you want and also add code whatever you tried.

Comment: I want the user to be able to blur the image using the drawing

Comment: start with [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/481825d2e4504479e1c585fdbcbc8d0a)

Comment: Is there a clear way to draw a blurry line with a brush like this video?

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-story-a1b2a.appspot.com/o/WhatsApp%20Video%202020-02-20%20at%205.02.02%20AM.mp4?alt=media&token=45a10d3f-8be2-4a7a-9539-86c984a6d151

@pskink

Comment: i have no idea what you mean

Comment: Can you watch this video? 
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-story-a1b2a.appspot.com/o/WhatsApp%20Video%202020-02-20%20at%205.02.02%20AM.mp4?alt=media&token=45a10d3f-8be2-4a7a-9539-86c984a6d151
@pskink

Comment: Did you get your answer? @haneensaadeh

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      YourImageWidget(),
      new BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3.0, sigmaY: 3.0),
        child: new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0)),
        ),
      ),

    ],
  )
```

Comment: `BackdropFilter`? in `CustomPainter`?

Comment: Of course not, replace CustomPainter with YourImageWidget().

Comment: he asks: "How **to blur a specific position** in the picture using CustomPainter in flutter"

Comment: I want the user to be able to blur the image using the drawing, not statically